# Convert Dictionary<string,string> to semicolon separated string in c#

Tags: c#

Simple one to start the day, given a `Dictionary<string, string>` as follows:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myDict["A"] = "1";
myDict["B"] = "2";
myDict["C"] = "3";
myDict["D"] = "4";
```

I wish to create a string: `"A=1;B=2;C=3;D=4"`

An example implementation:

```
var myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
bool first = true;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in myDict)
{
    if (first)
    {
        first = false;
    }
    else
    {
        myStringBuilder.Append(";");
    }

    myStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}

var myDesiredOutput = myStringBuilder.ToString();
```

Note the dictionary is likely to have less than 10 items which suggests that a StringBuilder is overkill.

What alternative implementations are more succinct / efficient? Does the framework have any features that will help?

Answer (score 336, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

string s = string.Join(";", myDict.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value).ToArray());
```

(And if you're using .NET 4, or newer, then you can omit the final `ToArray` call.)

Comment: Nice :-) However, I'd use String.Format("{0}={1}", x.Key, x.Value) instead of the + operator

Comment: Edited according to comments.

Comment: @Amittai, @the_drow: You might prefer `string.Format`; I prefer `k+"="+v` for simple concatenations like this. Each to their own I guess...

Comment: If you don't care about the exact output format, you can do `string.Join(", ", myDict)`. It will output in the form `[A, 1], [B, 2], [C, 3], [D, 4]`

Answer (score 41):

Another option is to use the Aggregate extension rather than Join:

```
String s = myDict.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value).Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + ";" + s2);
```

Comment: perfect linq style!

Answer (score 6):

For Linq to work over `Dictionary` you need at least [.Net v3.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netframework-3.5) and `using System.Linq;`.

Some alternatives:

```
string myDesiredOutput = string.Join(";", myDict.Select(x => string.Join("=", x.Key, x.Value)));
```

or

```
string myDesiredOutput = string.Join(";", myDict.Select(x => $"{x.Key}={x.Value}"));
```

If you can't use Linq for some reason, use `Stringbuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var isFirst = true;
foreach(var x in myDict) 
{
  if (isFirst) 
  {
    sb.Append($"{x.Key}={x.Value}");
    isFirst = false;
  }
  else
    sb.Append($";{x.Key}={x.Value}"); 
}

string myDesiredOutput = sb.ToString();
```

myDesiredOutput:

```
A=1;B=2;C=3;D=4
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var joinedString= string.Join(";", myDict.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value));
```

reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join__1_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__

Comment: This is the same answer @LukeH has above.

Comment: dude it is not same , there is no need to use ToArray(). Please dont downvote my answer.

Comment: It is the same - he mentions the removal of `ToArray()` when using higher versions of the framework.